# Memory leak in product save loop

Tags: product, magento2.3, import, product-import, memory-leak

I'm trying to import ~5000 products from XML, but the execution time and memory usage increases in each loop, resulting in a long import process.
Test code to demonstrate:

```
<?php

namespace Test\Product\Console\Command;

use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Math\Random;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;

/**
 * Class Test
 * @package Test\Product\Console\Command
 */
class Test extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var ProductInterfaceFactory
     */
    private $productFactory;

    /**
     * @var ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var Random
     */
    private $random;

    /**
     * @var State
     */
    private $state;

    /**
     * Test constructor.
     * @param ProductInterfaceFactory $productFactory
     * @param ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
     * @param Random $random
     * @param State $state
     * @param string|null $name
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductInterfaceFactory $productFactory,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        Random $random,
        State $state,
        string $name = null
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->random = $random;
        $this->state = $state;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('test');
        $this->setDescription('Test');

        parent::configure();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $this->state->setAreaCode(Area::AREA_GLOBAL);

        for ($i = 0; $i <= 15; $i++) {
            $rand = $this->random->getRandomString(15);
            /** @var ProductInterface $product */
            $product = $this->productFactory->create();
            $product->setSku($rand);
            $product->setName($rand);
            $product->setAttributeSetId(4);
            $product->setTypeId('simple');
            $product->setPrice(10);
            echo sprintf('Memory usage before save: %s%s', memory_get_usage(), PHP_EOL);
            $this->productRepository->save($product);
            echo sprintf('Memory usage after save: %s%s', memory_get_usage(), PHP_EOL);
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Memory usage before save: 58376560
Memory usage after save: 89150656
Memory usage before save: 89141752
Memory usage after save: 89171592
Memory usage before save: 89162688
Memory usage after save: 89192848
Memory usage before save: 89183944
Memory usage after save: 89213784
Memory usage before save: 89204880
Memory usage after save: 89235680
Memory usage before save: 89226776
Memory usage after save: 89256616
Memory usage before save: 89247712
Memory usage after save: 89277552
Memory usage before save: 89268648
Memory usage after save: 89298488
Memory usage before save: 89289584
Memory usage after save: 89323264
Memory usage before save: 89314360
Memory usage after save: 89344200
Memory usage before save: 89335296
Memory usage after save: 89365136
Memory usage before save: 89356232
Memory usage after save: 89386072
Memory usage before save: 89377168
Memory usage after save: 89407008
Memory usage before save: 89398104
Memory usage after save: 89427944
Memory usage before save: 89419040
Memory usage after save: 89448880
Memory usage before save: 89439976
Memory usage after save: 89469816
```

Tried to instantiate the $product object only once, and then clear it in each loop, but that didn't help much.

Any tips or suggestions on how to avoid the memory leak? Maybe a hint on what's causing it? Would like to import products without some custom MySQL queries.

Comment: how are you reading xml ? Is it from file? How often will You do that ?

Comment: Your code seems right. Magento 2, need huge memory usage on during import  during import. I suggest you can use  implement this code at `AWS Lamda` then it might be help you. Also,  you do not use  using  `magento2 Msi` then disable MSE related module `https://github.com/yireo/magento2-replace-inventory`